# Returning a named function from inside an AngularJS compile function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following **AngularJS directive**:

```
angular.module('field-directive', ['input.html', 'textarea.html', 'select.html'])

.directive('field', function($compile, $http, $templateCache, $interpolate) {

  // Load a template, possibly from the $templateCache, and instantiate a DOM element from it
  function loadTemplate(template) {
    return $http.get(template, {cache:$templateCache}).then(function(response) {
      return angular.element(response.data);
    }, function(response) {
      throw new Error('Template not found: ' + template);
    });
  }

  // Find the "input" element in the template.  It will be one of input, select or textarea.
  // We need to ensure it is wrapped in jqLite\jQuery
  function findInputElement(templateElement) {
    return angular.element(templateElement.find('input')[0] || templateElement.find('select')[0] || templateElement.find('textarea')[0]);
  }

  function findLabelElement(templateElement) {
    return templateElement.find('label');
  }

  // Search through the originalDirective's element for elements that contain information about how to map
  // validation keys to messages
  function getValidationMessageMap(originalElement) {
    // Find all the <validator> child elements and extract their (key, message) info
    var validationMessages = {};
    angular.forEach(originalElement.find('validator'), function(element) {
      // Wrap the element in jqLite/jQuery
      element = angular.element(element);
      // Store the message info to be provided to the scope later
      // The content of the validation element may include interpolation {{}}
      // so we will actually store a function created by the $interpolate service
      // To get the interpolated message we will call this function with the scope. e.g.
      //   var messageString = getMessage(scope);
      validationMessages[element.attr('key')] = $interpolate(element.text());
    });
    return validationMessages;
  }

  // Find the content that will go into the new label
  // Label is provided as a <label> child element of the original element
  function getLabelContent(element) {
    var label = element.find('label');
    return label[0] && label.html();
  }

  return {
    restrict:'E',
    priority: 100,        // We need this directive to happen before ng-model
    terminal: true,       // We are going to deal with this element
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
      if ( attrs.ngRepeat || attrs.ngSwitch || attrs.uiIf ) {
        throw new Error('The ng-repeat, ng-switch and ui-if directives are not supported on the same element as the field directive.');
      }
      if ( !attrs.ngModel ) {
        throw new Error('The ng-model directive must appear on the field element');
      }

      // Extract the label and validation message info from the directive's original element
      var validationMessages = getValidationMessageMap(element);
      var labelContent = getLabelContent(element);

      // Clear the directive's original element now that we have extracted what we need from it
      element.html('');

      return function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        // Load up the template for this kind of field, default to the simple input if none given
        loadTemplate(attrs.template || 'input.html').then(function(templateElement) {
          // Set up the scope - the template will have its own scope, which is a child of the directive's scope
          var childScope = scope.$new();
          // Attach a copy of the message map to the scope
          childScope.$validationMessages = angular.copy(validationMessages);
          // Generate an id for the field from the ng-model expression and the current scope
          // We replace dots with underscores to work with browsers and ngModel lookup on the FormController
          // We couldn't do this in the compile function as we need to be able to calculate the unique id from the scope
          childScope.$fieldId = attrs.ngModel.replace('.', '_').toLowerCase() + '_' + childScope.$id;
          childScope.$fieldLabel = labelContent;

          // Update the $fieldErrors array when the validity of the field changes
          childScope.$watch('$field.$dirty && $field.$error', function(errorList) {
            childScope.$fieldErrors = [];
            angular.forEach(errorList, function(invalid, key) {
              if ( invalid ) {
                childScope.$fieldErrors.push(key);
              }
            });
          }, true);


          // Copy over all left over attributes to the input element
          // We can't use interpolation in the template for directives such as ng-model
          var inputElement = findInputElement(templateElement);
          angular.forEach(attrs.$attr, function (original, normalized) {
            var value = element.attr(original);
            inputElement.attr(original, value);
          });

          // Wire up the input (id and name) and its label (for).
          // We need to set the input element's name here before we compile the template.
          // If we leave it to be interpolated at the next $digest the formController doesn't pick it up
          inputElement.attr('name', childScope.$fieldId);
          inputElement.attr('id', childScope.$fieldId);
          var labelElement = templateElement.find('label');
          labelElement.attr('for', childScope.$fieldId);
          // Update the label's contents
          labelElement.html(labelContent);

          // Place our template as a child of the original element.
          // This needs to be done before compilation to ensure that it picks up any containing form.
          element.append(templateElement);

          // We now compile and link our template here in the postLink function
          // This allows the ng-model directive on our template's <input> element to access the ngFormController
          $compile(templateElement)(childScope);

          // Now that our template has been compiled and linked we can access the <input> element's ngModelController
          childScope.$field = inputElement.controller('ngModel');
        });
      };
    }
  };
});
```

The question I have is about this **specific portion of code**:

```
return function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
...
```

Notice that a **named function** is being returned here.

I would like to know whether the **name of the returned function matters for AngularJS**.

In other words if I had used **some other name** or **no name at all**, would AngularJS complain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't matter at all, you can use any name or no name at all. Why you would want to use a named function is to give meaning, for instance look at the following code from Angular source:

```
var ngValueDirective = function() {
  return {
    priority: 100,
    compile: function(tpl, tplAttr) {
      if (CONSTANT_VALUE_REGEXP.test(tplAttr.ngValue)) {
        return function ngValueConstantLink(scope, elm, attr) {
          attr.$set('value', scope.$eval(attr.ngValue));
        };
      } else {
        return function ngValueLink(scope, elm, attr) {
          scope.$watch(attr.ngValue, function valueWatchAction(value) {
            attr.$set('value', value);
          });
        };
      }
    }
  };
};
```

This has two linking functions depending on some condition. Naming them helps show what their intended use is.

Comment: that's not the only advantage - with named functions, you can refer to the function from within the function itself. [see how john demonstrated this](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#11).

Comment: I'm sure there are other advantages as well. Just pointed the obvious one out.